# $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)~dt \implies F(1)=f(0)+\int_0^1(1-t)f'(t)~dt$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

*f* is differentiable and has a continuous derviative, and $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)~dt$. Based on this assumption, I have the following statement which I need to determine whether it's true or false: $$F(1)=f(0)+\int_0^1(1-t)f'(t)~dt$$

My try at determining the validity of that statement: $$(1)=f(0)+\int_0^1 (1-t)f'(t)~dt=f(0)+\int_0^1 f'(t) ~dt-\int_0^1 f'(t)t ~dt=\left [f(t) -f(t)t+F(t) \right ]_0^1=f(0)+f(1)-f(1)+F(1)-f(0)-F(0)=F(1)-F(0)$$

I probably messed up somewhere, but it does look like it's correct? In any case, I determined the statement is true based on the above. Am I wrong?

Edit: We also know based on the assumption that $F(0)=0$. Thank's to Sciona for reminding me to add that.

Comment: The derivation seems correct ! Just note that $F(0) = \int_0^0 f(t)\,dt = 0$ !